# Unable to do client-server communication via sockets in Python

Tags: python, sockets, client-server

I have been banging my head against a socket issue for the last two weeks to no avail. I have a setup of 12 'client' machines and one server machine. The server is given a large task, splits it into 12 smaller tasks and then distributes them to the 12 clients. The clients churn away and once they finish their task, they are supposed to let the server know that they have finished via socket communication. For some reason, this has only been working spottily or not at all (both, the server and the clients, just sit in the while loop).

Here is the code on the server:

```
socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
socket.bind(('localhost', RandomPort))
socket.listen(0)
socket.settimeout(0.9)

[Give all the clients their tasks, then do the following:]

while 1:
    data = 'None'
    IP = [0,0]   
    try:
        Client, IP = socket.accept()
        data = Client.recv(1024)
        if data == 'Done':
            Client.send('Thanks')
        for ClientIP in ClientIPList():
            if ClientIP == IP[0] and data == 'Done':
                FinishedCount += 1 
            if FinishedCount == 12:
                break
    except:
        pass
```

Here is the code on all the clients:

```
[Receive task from server and execute. Once finished, do the following:]

while 1:
    try:
        f = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        f.connect((IPofServer, RandomPort)) 
        f.settimeout(0.5)
        f.send('Done')
        data = f.recv(1024)
        if data == 'Thanks':
            f.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
            f.close()
            break
    except:
        f.close()
        time.sleep(2+random.random()*5)
```

I have used Wireshark and found that the packets are flying around. Yet, the "FinishedCount" never seems to increase... Is there anything glaringly wrong that I have missed in setting this up? This is my first exposure to sockets....

Thank you all for your help in advance!

EDIT: I've made the following changes to the code:

On the server: socket.listen is now socket.listen(5)

Comment: Tip:  you should never use uppercase as the first letter of a variable.  That syntax should always be left for class names.  Question: why is the client in a while 1 loop?  Why not just send once to say "Im done" then move on?  Is the data not sending the first time?

Comment: I put it in a while loop because I'm worried about the connection being refused by the server because he's already handling other clients. It's my attempt at making sure we have a positive handshake...

Comment: If you can reduce the packets to a reasonable number, why not print out each 'data' as it's read by the server? If you have, for example, an extra newline, your equality test will never be true. It might be useful to see what data is actually being sent/received.

Comment: Hmm, interesting - if I `print data` nothing never actually prints. In fact, the server loop fails at `socket.accept`.

Comment: Just a sanity check -- are the client/server values for `RandomPort` the same?

Comment: Yes, they are - I pass them down to the clients.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, this took me a while but I think I figured out what was causing this:

1. glglgl's answer is correct - using 'localhost' causes the machine to
   only listen to itself and not to other machines on the network. This
   was the main culprit.
2. Increasing the number allowed in the que from 0 to 5 reduced the
   likelihood of getting a "connection refused" error on the client
   side.
3. I made the mistake of assuming that socket connections in an infinite
   while loop can be shut down infinitely fast - however, having an
   infinite while loop on both sides sometimes caused a client to
   sometimes be counted twice because the while loops were not
   synchronized. This, of course, caused 'client-agnostic'
   finishedCount to increase twice which led the server the believe all
   clients were done when they weren't. Using chown's code (thank you
   chown!), this can be dealt with like this:

   ```
   def main():
       sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
       sock.bind((HOST, PORT))
       sock.listen(0)

       FINISHEDCLIENTS = []

       while 1:
           data = 'None'
           IP = [0, 0]
           try:
               client, ip = sock.accept()
               data = client.recv(1024)
               print "%s: Server recieved: '%s'" % (time.ctime(), data)

               if data == 'Done':
                   print "%s: Server sending: 'Thanks'" % time.ctime()
                   client.send('Thanks')

                   if ip[0] in CLIENT_IPS and ip[0] not in FINISHEDCLIENTS: 
                       FINISHEDCLIENTS.append(ip[0])

                       if len(FINISHEDCLIENTS) == 12:
                           #raise MyException
                           break

           except Exception, e:
               print "%s: Server Exception - %s" % (time.ctime(), e)
   ```

   On the client side, I changed the code to this (where of course,
   RandomPort is the same as the one used in the server script above):

   ```
   SentFlag = 0
   data = 'no'
   while SentFlag == 0:
       try:
           f = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
           f.connect((IPofServer, RandomPort))
           f.settimeout(20)
           f.send('Done')
           data = f.recv(1024)
           if data == 'Thanks':
               f.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
               f.close()
               SentFlag = 1
       except:
           f.close()
           time.sleep(2*random.random())
   ```

PS: My understanding of .shutdown() vs .close() is that closes the connection but not necessarily the socket if it is engaged in another communication. .shutdown() shuts down the socket no matter what else it is doing. I don't have any proof for this though.

I think that should do it - thank you all again for helping fix this code!

Answer (score 2):

Your server has two bugs:

First, this will break out of the inner `for` loop, not the `while` loop:

```
if FinishedCount == 12:
    break
```

Your `while` loop has no termination condition.

Second, this pattern:

```
try:
    ...
except:
    pass
```

Should *never* be used. You're swallowing up every single exception and ignoring it. That is bad practice, and will lead to bugs.  It should be:

```
try:
    ...
except OneExceptionIWantToIgnore:
    pass
except:
    raise
```

Fix those two and get back to us with results.

Comment: The `except: raise` is the same as not having an uncoditional `except:` in there at all.  But this is correct about the `break` not ending the while loop.

Comment: @chown This is true, but I find it to be a bit clearer/easier to understand, as it's explicit that the only exception to be ignored is the one specified.

Comment: Good catch about the break - I fixed that.

Once I added the raise, I got the `socket.timeout: timed out`  error. I tried setting the socket to non-blocking and that resulted in the `[Error 11] Resource Temporarily unavailable` error. I originally did the except the way it was to avoid the time-outs - I expect those to happen while the clients are not yet communicating with the server.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the issue here is the use of `RandomPort`.  Each client and the server need to be sending/receiving on the same port for this to work.  Also, the `for ClientIP in ClientIPList(): if ClientIP == IP[0] and data == 'Done':` loop is a little redundant and unnecessary.  It can be replaced with `if ip[0] in clientIpList:` and placed inside the `if data == 'Done':` above it.

A few other thoughts; never name a variable the same name as something you have imported (like `socket = socket.socket(..)`) because then you will not be able to use the imported library anymore.  And unless the client/server are both running on the same system or within the same sub-net, `settimeout(0.5)` is way to short.

I merged your code with some [example code](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#example) from the [python `socket` documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html) and came up with something that works that you should be able to easily adapt for your needs.  Here are the scripts; the output from running the server and 12 clients is pasted below.

server.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# server.py

import sys
import socket
import time

HOST = ''
PORT = 50008

CLIENT_IPS = ["10.10.1.11"]

## No longer necessary if the nested loop isn't needed
#class MyException(Exception):
#    pass

def main():
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.bind((HOST, PORT))
    sock.listen(0)

    finishedCount = 0

    while 1:
        data = 'None'
        IP = [0, 0]
        try:
            client, ip = sock.accept()
            data = client.recv(1024)
            print "%s: Server recieved: '%s'" % (time.ctime(), data)

            if data == 'Done':
                print "%s: Server sending: 'Thanks'" % time.ctime()
                client.send('Thanks')

                if ip[0] in CLIENT_IPS:
                    finishedCount += 1
                    print "%s: Finished Count: '%d'" % (time.ctime(), finishedCount)

                    if finishedCount == 12:
                        #raise MyException
                        break

        except Exception, e:
            print "%s: Server Exception - %s" % (time.ctime(), e)

        #except MyException:
        #    print "%s: All clients accounted for.  Server ending, goodbye!" % time.ctime()
        #    break

    # close down the socket, ignore closing exceptions
    try:
        sock.close()
    except:
        pass
    print "%s: All clients accounted for.  Server ending, goodbye!" % time.ctime()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

client.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# client.py

import sys
import time
import socket
import random

HOST = '10.10.1.11'
PORT = 50008

def main(n):
    while 1:
        try:
            s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            s.connect((HOST, PORT))

            s.send('Done')
            print "%s: Client %d: Sending - 'Done'.." % (time.ctime(), n)

            data = s.recv(1024)
            print "%s: Client %d: Recieved - '%s'" % (time.ctime(), n, data)

            if data == 'Thanks':
                break

        except Exception, e:
            print "%s: Client %d: Exception - '%s'" % (time.ctime(), n, e)
            time.sleep(2 + random.random() * 5)
        finally:
            try:
                s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
            except:
                pass
            finally:
                try:
                    s.close()
                except:
                    pass

    print "%s: Client %d: Finished, goodbye!" % (time.ctime(), n)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) > 1 and sys.argv[1].isdigit():
        sys.exit(main(int(sys.argv[1])))
```

Output from running 12 Clients:

```
[ 10:52 jon@hozbox.com ~/SO/python ]$ for x in {1..12}; do ./client.py $x && sleep 2; done
Fri Nov 18 10:52:44 2011: Client 1: Sending - 'Done'..
Fri Nov 18 10:52:44 2011: Client 1: Recieved - 'Thanks'
Fri Nov 18 10:52:44 2011: Client 1: Finished, goodbye!
Fri Nov 18 10:52:46 2011: Client 2: Sending - 'Done'..
Fri Nov 18 10:52:46 2011: Client 2: Recieved - 'Thanks'
Fri Nov 18 10:52:46 2011: Client 2: Finished, goodbye!
Fri Nov 18 10:52:48 2011: Client 3: Sending - 'Done'..
Fri Nov 18 10:52:48 2011: Client 3: Recieved - 'Thanks'
Fri Nov 18 10:52:48 2011: Client 3: Finished, goodbye!
Fri Nov 18 10:52:50 2011: Client 4: Sending - 'Done'..
Fri Nov 18 10:52:50 2011: Client 4: Recieved - 'Thanks'
Fri Nov 18 10:52:50 2011: Client 4: Finished, goodbye!
Fri Nov 18 10:52:52 2011: Client 5: Sending - 'Done'..
Fri Nov 18 10:52:52 2011: Client 5: Recieved - 'Thanks'
Fri Nov 18 10:52:52 2011: Client 5: Finished, goodbye!
Fri Nov 18 10:52:54 2011: Client 6: Sending - 'Done'..
Fri Nov 18 10:52:54 2011: Client 6: Recieved - 'Thanks'
Fri Nov 18 10:52:54 2011: Client 6: Finished, goodbye!
Fri Nov 18 10:52:56 2011: Client 7: Sending - 'Done'..
Fri Nov 18 10:52:56 2011: Client 7: Recieved - 'Thanks'
Fri Nov 18 10:52:56 2011: Client 7: Finished, goodbye!
Fri Nov 18 10:52:58 2011: Client 8: Sending - 'Done'..
Fri Nov 18 10:52:58 2011: Client 8: Recieved - 'Thanks'
Fri Nov 18 10:52:58 2011: Client 8: Finished, goodbye!
Fri Nov 18 10:53:01 2011: Client 9: Sending - 'Done'..
Fri Nov 18 10:53:01 2011: Client 9: Recieved - 'Thanks'
Fri Nov 18 10:53:01 2011: Client 9: Finished, goodbye!
Fri Nov 18 10:53:03 2011: Client 10: Sending - 'Done'..
Fri Nov 18 10:53:03 2011: Client 10: Recieved - 'Thanks'
Fri Nov 18 10:53:03 2011: Client 10: Finished, goodbye!
Fri Nov 18 10:53:05 2011: Client 11: Sending - 'Done'..
Fri Nov 18 10:53:05 2011: Client 11: Recieved - 'Thanks'
Fri Nov 18 10:53:05 2011: Client 11: Finished, goodbye!
Fri Nov 18 10:53:07 2011: Client 12: Sending - 'Done'..
Fri Nov 18 10:53:07 2011: Client 12: Recieved - 'Thanks'
Fri Nov 18 10:53:07 2011: Client 12: Finished, goodbye!
[ 10:53 jon@hozbox.com ~/SO/python ]$
```

Output from server running at the same time:

```
[ 10:52 jon@hozbox.com ~/SO/python ]$ ./server.py
Fri Nov 18 10:52:44 2011: Server recieved: 'Done'
Fri Nov 18 10:52:44 2011: Server sending: 'Thanks'
Fri Nov 18 10:52:44 2011: Finished Count: '1'
Fri Nov 18 10:52:46 2011: Server recieved: 'Done'
Fri Nov 18 10:52:46 2011: Server sending: 'Thanks'
Fri Nov 18 10:52:46 2011: Finished Count: '2'
Fri Nov 18 10:52:48 2011: Server recieved: 'Done'
Fri Nov 18 10:52:48 2011: Server sending: 'Thanks'
Fri Nov 18 10:52:48 2011: Finished Count: '3'
Fri Nov 18 10:52:50 2011: Server recieved: 'Done'
Fri Nov 18 10:52:50 2011: Server sending: 'Thanks'
Fri Nov 18 10:52:50 2011: Finished Count: '4'
Fri Nov 18 10:52:52 2011: Server recieved: 'Done'
Fri Nov 18 10:52:52 2011: Server sending: 'Thanks'
Fri Nov 18 10:52:52 2011: Finished Count: '5'
Fri Nov 18 10:52:54 2011: Server recieved: 'Done'
Fri Nov 18 10:52:54 2011: Server sending: 'Thanks'
Fri Nov 18 10:52:54 2011: Finished Count: '6'
Fri Nov 18 10:52:56 2011: Server recieved: 'Done'
Fri Nov 18 10:52:56 2011: Server sending: 'Thanks'
Fri Nov 18 10:52:56 2011: Finished Count: '7'
Fri Nov 18 10:52:58 2011: Server recieved: 'Done'
Fri Nov 18 10:52:58 2011: Server sending: 'Thanks'
Fri Nov 18 10:52:58 2011: Finished Count: '8'
Fri Nov 18 10:53:01 2011: Server recieved: 'Done'
Fri Nov 18 10:53:01 2011: Server sending: 'Thanks'
Fri Nov 18 10:53:01 2011: Finished Count: '9'
Fri Nov 18 10:53:03 2011: Server recieved: 'Done'
Fri Nov 18 10:53:03 2011: Server sending: 'Thanks'
Fri Nov 18 10:53:03 2011: Finished Count: '10'
Fri Nov 18 10:53:05 2011: Server recieved: 'Done'
Fri Nov 18 10:53:05 2011: Server sending: 'Thanks'
Fri Nov 18 10:53:05 2011: Finished Count: '11'
Fri Nov 18 10:53:07 2011: Server recieved: 'Done'
Fri Nov 18 10:53:07 2011: Server sending: 'Thanks'
Fri Nov 18 10:53:07 2011: Finished Count: '12'
Fri Nov 18 10:53:07 2011: All clients accounted for.  Server ending, goodbye!
[ 10:53 jon@hozbox.com ~/SO/python ]$
```

Comment: I'm looking at the [documentation for `socket.close()`](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.socket.close) and it explicitly states that calling `.shutdown()` has additional effects.  Just `.close()` definitely doesn't "do it for you".

Comment: @AndréCaron Hmm, my mistake.. maybe I was thinking about stopping threads at the time... fixed answer.

Comment: This is nice, thank you chown. The socket naming was just conceptual - it's not the way I actually have it implemented. See the answer that I posted - I had to do a couple of additional edits.

Answer (score 0):

Calling listen(0) sets no backlog, so you are much more likely to get a connection refused.  The server-side socket is never closed, also.  Get rid of the try/excepts for now so you can see what the real problems are.  Handle explicit socket.error exceptions otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

If you do

```
socket.bind(('localhost', RandomPort))
```

your server machine will only accept connections from itself, i. e. localhost.

Instead, do

```
socket.bind(('', RandomPort))
```

to listen on all interfaces.

Comment: Oh, and before I forget it - start getting familiar with `AF_INET6` and/or `getaddrinfo()` for new applications.